# Binding to the DataContext of the Item in the ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

How can I bind to the Item's DataContext in the ItemsControl from within a nested data template (a data template of a control within the item's data template)?

I can't use `TemplatedParent`, because it's double templated.
And I can't figure out how to use `FindAncestor,AncestorType` because I don't know what the type is for each Item.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you have:

```
- ItemsControl
  |- ItemTemplate                    Item.DataContext<--|
     |- Button                                          | 
        |- ContentTemplate <-- Bind something in this to|
```

If that is the case, what you're looking for is `ContentPresenter`. That is the type of container that `ItemsControl` generates. The problem is that you're going to have multiple `ContentPresenter` ancestors. You can do handle this with the [`AncestorLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestorlevel.aspx) property of the `RelativeSource`.

So, in my example, the `DataTemplate` of the `Button` can access the `DataContext` of the row by:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}, AncestorLevel=2}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: ContentPresenter!! That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Finally found it after searching 3 hours! This should have more votes to be top visible. Thank you.